# netsh hostednetwork disable WPA2 encryption (open network)

Tags: windows, netsh, internet-sharing, ics, wpa2

Internet connection sharing in windows is nice and easy using Virtual Wifi Mini-Port Adapters and the netsh command:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<mySSID> key=<password>
```

<strike>1) Is there anyway I can disable the default WPA2-Personal encryption over this method to have an open wireless access point?</strike>

2) If there isn't a documented way of achieving this, what would be a good place to start working backwards from and reverse engineering netsh to achieve an open wifi AP?

---

**EDIT:**
According to the [wireless hosted network website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there is no way to use the netsh tool to achieve an open access point.

> To provide protection for the wireless communications between the computer hosting SoftAP and the devices connecting to the SoftAP, the wireless Hosted Network requires that all devices connected use the WPA2-PSK/AES cipher suite.

Now the real question is, "What controls is netsh using in order to create an access point, and how can I leverage those tools?"

---

**EDIT2:** It seems that windows has an [ExtAP mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549858(v=vs.85).aspx) that is optional at the driver level. NDIS describes the way drivers must interact with the operating system. So, might be possible to write a kernel module that can reset the AP to open after netsh turns on the rest of the sharing stack. The drawbacks are kernel modules have to be signed with window$ and resetting the AP might mess with the sharing software / connection that is already running.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=WiFi-Hotspot_Key:1to8 key=12345678 keyUsage=persistent
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security
```

Comment: Consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state.